# How to generate a map showing more than one feature from the coverage layer of Atlas Generator in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile (point) with occurrence records of species. There are at least two features for each species, one for currently record and a second for past record.

I need to produce one map for each species and in this map I need both types of records with different styles. I tried to follow instructions of Automating Map Creation with Print Composer Atlas at http://www.qgistutorials.com/pt_BR/docs/automating_map_creation.html
But what I got was two maps per species: one with currently records, another with pas records. I think that the problem is at the expression that I used in style rule-based: `$id  =  @atlas_featureid` which gives me on map per feature.

I think that I need an expression that selects features based on the field that contains the species name and show only these features on the map.

Comment: Is the map extent supposed to change for each pair of points? Or it's always the same?

Comment: You won't be able to show more than one feature using  the "original" layer as coverage layer,  but you can prepare the right coverage layer dissolving the layer to create a multi-point layer. And use it in the atlas.